# Error with C++ MPI program which use MPI_Send & MPI_Recv

Tags: c++

I am new with `MPI` and trying to write test program where I use `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` to pass two numbers `"a"` and `"b"` between the root process which is `0` and the next which is `1`. But each time I get the same error: "Test.exe has triggered a breakpoint." Can you please help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    MPI_Status status;

    if (rank == 0) {
        a = 1;
        MPI_Send(&a,1,MPI_INTEGER,1,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&b, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        printf("Root has now B: ", rank, b);
    }
    else {
        b = 2;
        MPI_Recv(&a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&b, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Proc 1 has now B: ", rank, a);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return(0);  
}
```

Comment: You can't use `MPI_ANY_TAG` to send

Comment: Thank you. I have changed MPI_ANY_TAG in MPI_SEND to 1,but the problem remains